# BinaryWriter is giving a bad size

Tags: c#, binarywriter

```
short[,] out2 = new short[1201, 1201];

FileStream fs = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\\One_File\\result.hgt",
                               FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
                               FileAccess.Write);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

for (int i = 0; i < 1201; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < 1201; j++)
  {
    bw.Write(out2[i, j]);
  }
}
```

1201 * 1201 * 2 = **2 884 802 bytes**.

The size of the result file is **2 883 584 bytes**.

Why?

Comment: I would guess you're inspecting the contents before you've closed/disposed the stream in your code. `2883584` is a suspiciously round number in binary.

Comment: Did you close the file before inspecting it? If you put `using (FileStream fs = …) { … }` it will be deterministically flushed and closed when the using block ends so that is recommended practice.

Comment: Also if you smells like an `IDisposable`, use a `using` statement

Comment: Also you should do `using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs)) { ... }`.